# Cors Api Google Maps

Tags: php, angularjs, cors

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema feito em Silex/PHP e o frontEnd dele esta sendo feito em AngularJs, tenho um método nele que estou querendo que ele faça uma busca na API do Google Maps para me retornar uma determinada rota, mas toda vez me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O cabeçalho da requisição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu habilitar o cors com a extensão do Chrome funciona perfeitamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um index.php onde todas as requisições passam por ele, então inserir o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de tudo mas nada funciona, alguém já passou por isso ?

Comment: Não adianta adicionar os headers do CORS no seu site, o navegador vai verificar eles no endereço da API, ou seja, no endereço do Google, o qual você não tem controle. O que você precisa é ver o manual da API do google para ver o que está incorreto, mas pelo pouco que li já adianto que o uso do Distance Matrix é proibido pelo google para qualquer uso que não seja exibir a informação em um mapa do google maps.

Comment: Mas se eu pegar a url e colar no navegador ele me retorna o xml ou json normal.

Comment: Isso porque você abriu a URL no navegador manualmente, por ajax é diferente, o navegador bloqueia requisições ajax entre domínios diferentes a menos que ele libere o acesso pelo CORS. E como eu disse, você deve verificar o manual das APIs do Google, lá você deve encontrar o como fazer corretamente, incluindo a aquisição de uma chave de acesso que o Google usa para controlar acesso as APIs dele e em que casos pode ou não usar as APIs dele.

Comment: Leandro, OK. Vou verificar aqui.

Comment: Leandro não consegui ainda, mas só uma dúvida se eu habilitar o cross origin do chrome ele funciona !

Comment: Não se engane, o que esta extensão faz é desativar o recurso de segurança do navegador, ele faz o navegador funcionar como se o servidor respondesse com os headers do CORS, isso nunca deve ser usado como referência para se criar um programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A API do Google não suporta nem CORS nem JSONP, então você terá que fazer um proxy com o php. Algo assim:

```
$http.get('goog.php').then(
    function(res){
        console.info(res);
        if(res.status == 200){

        }
    }, function(error){
        //mensagem de erro
        console.info(error);
    }
);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=SUA_KEY';
$returned_content = get_data($url);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $returned_content;

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Se não tiver `curl`, usa alguma outra forma.